# Golang solution to Project Euler #81 (min path through a matrix)

Tags: algorithm, programming-challenge, matrix, search, go

[Project Euler problem 81](http://projecteuler.net/problem=81) asks:

> In the 5 by 5 matrix below,
>
> ```
> 131   673 234 103 18
> 201   96  342 965 150
> 630   803 746 422 111
> 537   699 497 121 956
> 805   732 524 37  331
> ```
>
> the minimal path sum from the top left to
>   the bottom right, by only moving to the right and down, is
>
> ```
> 131 → 201 → 96 → 342 → 746 → 422 → 121 → 37 → 331
> ```
>
> and is equal to 2427.
>
> Find the minimal path sum, in [`matrix.txt`](http://projecteuler.net/project/matrix.txt) (right click and 'Save
>   Link/Target As...'), a 31K text file containing a 80 by 80 matrix,
>   from the top left to the bottom right by only moving right and down.

Below is a Go solution using [uniform-cost search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform-cost_search) to build a search tree. It works on the toy small problem but on the 80x80 matrix it runs out of space. Could anyone that is up for a challenge help improve this still using this solution? By the way, this is the first program of any consequence I have written in Go and I am try to learn the language.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "container/heap"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

var matrix [][]int = make([][]int, 0, 80)

func main() {
    f, _ := os.Open("matrix.txt")
    r := bufio.NewReader(f)
    defer f.Close()
    for {

        s, ok := r.ReadString('\n')
        if ok == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        s = strings.Trim(s, "\n")
        stringArr := strings.Split(s, ",")
        tmp := make([]int, 0)
        for i := 0; i < 80; i++ {
            v, _ := strconv.Atoi(stringArr[i])
            tmp = append(tmp, v)
        }
        matrix = append(matrix, tmp)
    }
    //fmt.Println(matrix)
    fmt.Println(uniformCostSearch(treeNode{0, 0, 4445, 0}))
}

func (node treeNode) getPriority(y, x int) int {
    return matrix[y][x]
}

type Node interface {
    // Neighbors returns a slice of vertices that are adjacent to v.
    Neighbors(v Node) []Node
}

// An treeNode is something we manage in a priority queue.
type treeNode struct {
    X        int
    Y        int
    priority int // The priority of the item in the queue.
    Index    int // The index of the item in the heap.
}

func (node treeNode) Neighbors() []*treeNode {
    tmp := []*treeNode{ //&treeNode{X: node.X - 1, Y: node.Y},
        &treeNode{X: node.X + 1, Y: node.Y},
        //&treeNode{X: node.X, Y: node.Y - 1},
        &treeNode{X: node.X, Y: node.Y + 1}}
    childNodes := make([]*treeNode, 0)
    for _, n := range tmp {
        if n.X >= 0 && n.Y >= 0 && n.X <= 80 && n.Y <= 80 {
            n.priority = node.priority + n.getPriority(n.Y, n.X)
            childNodes = append(childNodes, n)
        }
    }
    return childNodes
}

func uniformCostSearch(startNode treeNode) int {
    frontier := make(PriorityQueue, 0, 10000)
    closedSet := make([]*treeNode, 0)
    heap.Push(&frontier, &startNode)
    for frontier.Len() > 0 {
        fmt.Println(frontier.Len())
        currentNode := heap.Pop(&frontier).(*treeNode)
        if currentNode.X == 79 && currentNode.Y == 79 {
            return currentNode.priority
        } else {
            closedSet = append(closedSet, currentNode)
        }
        possibleMoves := currentNode.Neighbors()
        for _, move := range possibleMoves {
            explored := false
            for _, seen := range closedSet {
                if seen.X == move.X && seen.Y == move.Y {
                    explored = true
                    break
                }
            }
            if explored {
                continue
            }
            // check that frontier does not contain this node and 
            // if it does then compare the cost so far
            for index, node := range frontier {
                if node.X == move.X && node.Y == move.Y && move.priority < node.priority {
                    fmt.Println("removing")
                    heap.Remove(&frontier, index)
                    break
                }
            }
            heap.Push(&frontier, move)
        }
    }
    return -1
}

// A PriorityQueue implements heap.Interface and holds treeNodes.
type PriorityQueue []*treeNode

func (pq PriorityQueue) Len() int {
    return len(pq)
}

func (pq PriorityQueue) Less(i, j int) bool {
    // We want Pop to give us the lowest priority so we use greater than here.
    return pq[i].priority < pq[j].priority
}

func (pq PriorityQueue) Swap(i, j int) {
    pq[i], pq[j] = pq[j], pq[i]
    pq[i].Index = i
    pq[j].Index = j
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Push(x interface{}) {
    // Push and Pop use pointer receivers because they modify the slice's length,
    // not just its contents.
    // To simplify indexing expressions in these methods, we save a copy of the
    // slice object. We could instead write (*pq)[i].
    a := *pq
    n := len(a)
    a = a[0 : n+1]
    item := x.(*treeNode)
    item.Index = n
    a[n] = item
    *pq = a
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Pop() interface{} {
    a := *pq
    n := len(a)
    item := a[n-1]
    item.Index = -1 // for safety
    *pq = a[0 : n-1]
    return item
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be less fragile and more idiomatic. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "container/heap"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type Matrix [][]int

type Node struct {
    x, y int
}

type Item struct {
    value    Node
    priority int
    index    int
}

type PriorityQueue []*Item

func (pq PriorityQueue) Len() int { return len(pq) }

func (pq PriorityQueue) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return pq[i].priority < pq[j].priority
}

func (pq PriorityQueue) Swap(i, j int) {
    pq[i], pq[j] = pq[j], pq[i]
    pq[i].index = i
    pq[j].index = j
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Push(x interface{}) {
    a := *pq
    n := len(a)
    item := x.(*Item)
    item.index = n
    a = append(a, item)
    *pq = a
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Pop() interface{} {
    a := *pq
    n := len(a)
    item := a[n-1]
    item.index = -1
    *pq = a[0 : n-1]
    return item
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) changePriority(item *Item, priority int) {
    heap.Remove(pq, item.index)
    item.priority = priority
    heap.Push(pq, item)
}

func readMatrix() (Matrix, error) {
    var matrix Matrix
    file, err := os.Open(`matrix.txt`)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer file.Close()
    rdr := bufio.NewReader(file)
    for {
        line, err := rdr.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF && len(line) == 0 {
                break
            }
            return nil, err
        }
        var row []int
        for _, s := range strings.Split(line[:len(line)-1], ",") {
            n, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            row = append(row, n)
        }
        matrix = append(matrix, row)
    }
    return matrix, nil
}

func (i Item) neighbors(matrix Matrix) []*Item {
    items := make([]*Item, 0, 2)
    x, y, p := i.value.x, i.value.y, i.priority
    if x := x + 1; x < len(matrix[y]) {
        items = append(items, &Item{value: Node{x, y}, priority: p + matrix[y][x]})
    }
    if y := y + 1; y < len(matrix) {
        items = append(items, &Item{value: Node{x, y}, priority: p + matrix[y][x]})
    }
    return items
}

func UniformCostSearch(matrix Matrix) (int, error) {
    if len(matrix) < 0 || len(matrix[0]) < 0 {
        return 0, errors.New("UniformCostSearch: invalid root")
    }
    root := Item{value: Node{0, 0}, priority: matrix[0][0]}
    if len(matrix) < 0 || len(matrix[len(matrix)-1]) < 0 {
        return 0, errors.New("UniformCostSearch: invalid goal")
    }
    goal := Node{len(matrix[len(matrix)-1]) - 1, len(matrix) - 1}
    frontier := make(PriorityQueue, 0, len(matrix)*len(matrix[len(matrix)-1]))
    heap.Push(&frontier, &root)
    explored := make(map[Node]bool)
    for {
        if len(frontier) == 0 {
            return 0, errors.New("UniformCostSearch: frontier is empty")
        }
        item := heap.Pop(&frontier).(*Item)
        if item.value == goal {
            return item.priority, nil
        }
        explored[item.value] = true
    neighbor:
        for _, n := range item.neighbors(matrix) {
            if explored[n.value] {
                continue neighbor
            }
            for _, f := range frontier {
                if f.value == n.value {
                    if f.priority > n.priority {
                        frontier.changePriority(f, n.priority)
                    }
                    continue neighbor
                }
            }
            heap.Push(&frontier, n)
        }
    }
    return 0, errors.New("UniformCostSearch: unreachable")
}

func main() {
    matrix, err := readMatrix()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    minPathSum, err := UniformCostSearch(matrix)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(minPathSum)
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for this answer, but it would have been nice to explain the main changes that you did: it avoids the need to compare the two versions and trying to figure out the reasons of the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The uniform-cost search, an algorithm based on graph theory, is unnecessarily complex for this problem.  You should be able to use a dynamic programming algorithm instead, which requires just a matrix for storage.

Consider how you can reduce the problem to a base case.  Let's take the 5×5 example in the question, and consider just the bottom-right 2×2 submatrix:

```
 121  956
  37  331
```

Starting at 331, the minimal path to the bottom-right is 331.  Starting at 37, the minimum distance is 37 + 331 = 368, because you must go right.  Starting at 956, the minimum distance is 956 + 331 = 1287, because you must go down.  Starting at 121, what do you do? Since 368 < 1287, it's cheaper to go down and join the 37 → 331 path, for a distance of 489.  Let's store all of that information as a matrix, where each element is the minimum distance from that element to the bottom-right corner:

```
 489 1287
 368  331
```

Expanding that matrix to 2×5 for the bottom two rows:

```
2222 1685  986  489 1287
2429 1624  892  368  331
```

Continuing all the way,

```
2427 2576 1903 1669 1566
2296 2095 1999 1876 1548
2852 2460 1657  911 1398
2222 1685  986  489 1287
2429 1624  892  368  331
```

Simply read out the answer from the top-left, which is 2427.

For an input matrix of dimensions *m* × *n*, the memory required is *m* × *n*.  Each element can be filled in O(1) time ("Is it cheaper to go right or go down?") for a total running time of O(*m* × *n*).  Any computer should be able to fill an 80 × 80 matrix effortlessly.  (The only concern might be overflow, but it turns out that the answer fits comfortably within 31 bits.)